# High poly to low poly

Tags: modeling

What’s the best way to make a low poly version of this for exporting to substance painter ? [image]

Comment: It’s 10k tris all together. I was wondering how I can make the buttons base lower poly..

Comment: will you use a Subdivision Surface modifier? Is it supposed to look low-poly? Because you could even delete some edge loops on the box and screen... For the button, you can select ring, checker deselect, select edge loops, then dissolve, as explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yptda_yKQIU

Comment: Or you can try new feature of Multires Modifier > Unsubdivide (in 2.9x)

Comment: Thanks guys il try both